# Autohotkey: modify text file without ever opening

Tags: autohotkey

I'll start off by saying that I've sat around trying to figure out this for a good 8hrs and now I'm coming here to ask for help.

I want to be able to have a text file that starts at 0 and will increase by 1 every time I press the hotkey. I want this to happen without having the file open. This will be used as a counter.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. How would you know the old value was `0` in order to increase it to `1` without opening the file to read it first? Also, you can't write to a file without opening it first. If you're just looking for an "in memory" counter, use a variable and store the value there.

Answer (score 2):

Ken made a point with regard to knowing the initial value. If you want to ADD a number at the bottom you can use:

```
fileappend, %Counter%`n, C:\Temp\Counter.txt
```

Or if you want to JUST have that one number:

```
filedelete, C:\Temp\Counter.txt
fileappend, %Counter%, C:\Temp\Counter.txt
```

If you want to store a variable, you can use the .ini files to store various variables.

```
IniWrite, %TextCounter%, %A_ScriptDir%\Counter.ini, Counter, Nr
IniRead, TextCounter, %A_ScriptDir%\Counter.ini, Counter, Nr
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question but it never got answered correctly.  If you want to store a single number in a file and then increment that number with a hotkey here is a simplified version of the process:

1. FileRead to store the current number from the file into a variable
2. FileDelete to delete the old file (if you don't delete the file each time, step 4 will turn the file into a list of numbers.
3. add 1 to the variable.
4. FileAppend to store the updated variable back in the file.